# Iterate over JSON Object for given list of keys using using Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list of keys

```
List<String> traverses = Arrays.asList("json1", "json2", "json3", "json4", "json5");
```

And below is the JSONObject

```
{
  "json1": {
    "json2": {
      "json3": {
        "json4": {
          "json5": {
            "data": [
              {
                "key": "9941",
                "doc_count": 14
              },
              {
                "key": "9920",
                "doc_count": 11
              },
              {
                "key": "9933",
                "doc_count": 11
              },
              {
                "key": "9931",
                "doc_count": 6
              },
              {
                "key": "9932",
                "doc_count": 4
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to iterate over above JSONObject for given json keys (traverses) using Lambda.

I have achieved it using traditional way

```
JSONObjet jsonObject = getJSONObject();
for (String key : traverses) {
    jsonObject = jsonObject.optJSONObject(key);
}
```

But looking for advanced way (using Stream/Lambda) to achieve the same.

Comment: Eventually I would like to fetch data of last key. So, in this case it would be json5.

Comment: @sushil It looks like you are trying to reinvent [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) (linked page includes tutorual/documentation at the end, don't miss it) . Are you aware of its existence?

Comment: Alexander, here I am developing a utility which will be used to extract JSONObject/JSONArray for give path as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to your loop:

```
JSONObjet jsonObject = traverses.stream().reduce(
        getJSONObject(),
        JSONObject::optJSONObject,
        (c1, c2) -> null);
```

It uses the [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) method which unfortunately requires a combiner argument that doesn't make much sense. Fortunately, it doesn't actually call it in this case, so I just made it return null.

Comment: Thanks k314159. This is what I was expecting.

Answer (score -1):

`traverses.stream().forEach((key)-> {jsonObject = jsonObject.optJSONObject(key); })`

Comment: Thanks, but it is throwing an exception. jsonObject should be final and if it is final then we cannot reassign it.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.